# I can't upload my program to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

I've not used my Arduino for about 2 months. Before this time it worked fine, but now when I want to upload my program I get this error:

> Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload.

I reset immediately after uploading but it doesn't work.What else should I do?
I'm using Ubuntu and the Arduino IDE.

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/diagnosing-arduino-problems-in-linux/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checks:

- Check if the board has power (probably it will).
- Check if the board is shown at the ports in the IDE (i.e. COM3: Arduino Uno).
- Check if you put the correct board in the IDE (e.g. Uno, Mega etc.).
- Check if you have multiple versions of the IDE running.
- Check if you have multiple IDEs installed.
- Check if you don't have the RX pin used while uploading a sketch.

Try the following:

- Use a different USB port on your computer
- Use a different USB cable
- Reinstall the Arduino IDE

Comment: Apparently, I had two versions installed and I was launching the wrong one (Arduino Genuino). Thank you

Comment: You are welcome ... you also can change the board in the IDE (I will update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a failure to upload the `Blink` program, with LED between #13 pin (+) and GND lead.

My solution was found by choosing other serial ports by stepping through the Serial Port options under the **Tools** menu

Selecting the correct port brought my new board to life!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange! How does this differ from the second point in the accepted answer?

Comment: Make sure you have a current limit resistor between #13 pin and the LED, like 270 ohm to 1K, 2K, in that range.  Don't burnout your IO pin.